# Run any C# method async. Possible?

Tags: c#, async-await

With Task.Run() you can run any method async, like

```
public int Increase(int val)
{
   return val + 1
}


int increased = await Task.Run ( () => return Increase(3) );
```

Is it possible to create an extension method, to just run any method as async like

```
var val = 1;
int increased = await Increased(3).AsAsync();
```

Comment: Your example doesn't even compile.  It should be `Task.Run(() => Increase(3));`

Comment: @juharr it is just a sample, no real code. I just wanna have a more simpler way compared to Task.Run().

Comment: It is not possible to use exactly the syntax you propose, not without some third-party tool that converts your syntax before the C# compiler gets it. You can do what you're trying to do on a limited (i.e. for specific method signatures) using extension methods, or on a broad basis with a tool that preprocesses the code, but there are far too many possible answers taking those approaches for this to be suitable for Stack Overflow, even assuming it was worth the trouble (which is debatable).

Comment: Look at this [example](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/blob/7cb932bcef6c5533e3a04a094b33959caff02d49/Source/AsyncExtensions.cs)

Comment: @MachineLearning that is your for enumerations based on an Enumerator. This works because the Enuemrator is called when the access on a value appears. This wont work for methods.

Comment: @PeterLiguda look at my answer...

Answer (score 2):

There is no way you could write an `AsAsync` method that would do what you're suggesting.  In the code `Increased(3).AsAsync()` You have already synchronously executed `Increased(3)` and computed its result before `AsAsync` is called.  It's too late to not execute that code before continuing.

Comment: So far it's clear it wont work like this simple. I know Async() is here called when the result of Increased is returned. But I search for a more simpler way to use async on *any* method.

Comment: @PeterLiguda Only way would be to create an extension of `Func<T>` then it would be called like `((Func<int>)(() => Increase(3))).AsAsync()` which is way worse than just calling `Task.Run` IMHO.

Comment: @juharr the reason why I am asking: I want to provide every method also as async and I don now want to have a lot of code which just executes the sync method with Task.Run(). I know it sometimes makes no sense but we have network methods which should be called async but the underlaying layer does not support async natively.

Comment: @PeterLiguda If the underlying layer doesn't support asynchronous operations then *you shouldn't be exposing asynchronous operations*.  It's effectively a lie.  Just expose the synchronous operations.  If a caller happens to need to perform the operations asynchronously, they can offload the work to another thread trivailly using `Task.Run`.  It's an anti-pattern to create versions of those methods that do all of their work in other threads when they don't support proper asynchrony.

Comment: @PeterLiguda What you are suggesting doesn't even sound all that useful.  You should only really use async where it makes sense, primarily with IO bound code.

Comment: @Servy do you have a document where it is really described as anti pattern? or just personal feeling?

Comment: @PeterLiguda So you don't trust the opinion of someone that has 148K rep on SO.  BTW I 100% agree with what Servy says based on experience.

Comment: @juharr it is not about the person of him. why that salty? I'm just interested of the background of an "anti pattern". Is this forbidden?

Comment: @PeterLiguda Whether or not something is an anti-pattern is, by definition, a matter of opinion.  It's a widely held opinion of experts in this field, but there's no "official" arbiter of what practices are good or bad.  You're welcome to do your research in the field and look at the opinions of others, if you would like to.

Comment: @PeterLiguda Stephen Toub [has said](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/24/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/) that adding asynchronous wrappers that only invoke Task.Run is not something you should do. His article explains the reasons the .NET team took this stance.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a CPU bound task and you want to use async as a convenient wrapper also for CPU bound operations, you can define an extension (vaguely based on this [GetTask](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/blob/7cb932bcef6c5533e3a04a094b33959caff02d49/Source/AsyncExtensions.cs#L51-L58) example)

```
public static class AsyncExtensions
{
    public static Task<U> AsCpuBoundAsync<T,U>(this Func<T,U> func, T t) 
    {
        return Task.Run(() => func(t));  
    }
}
```

to wrap a function

```
    public static int Increase(int val)
    {
       //doing CPU bound activities...
       return val + 1;
    }
```

as follows

```
   int increased = await ((Func<int,int>)(t =>
       Increase(t))).AsCpuBoundAsync(3);
```